# What system is behind the ordering of ANSI colors?

Tags: colors, ansi-colors

Sorry. Google banned me.

I'm trying to understand terminal special chars and colors. And what I can't understand is ordering of colors.

```
0 black
1 red
2 green
3 yellow
4 blue
5 magenta
6 cyan
7 white
```

RGYBMC... RGB + CMYK + drink time?

Please help Dora to find common sense.

Comment: You assume there is a reason and not just someone having picked that order when coming up with the colors in the first place. I'm not sure that's a valid assumption. I'm also not sure that anyone who wasn't involved in the process in the first place is likely to be able to offer any insight into this question (unless it made it into some history or spec text at some point).

Comment: Thanks for answer, Etan. Pfff random is not cool. I mean, programmer stuff nice to expect logical behavior. Ok then i write abstraction or will be googling every time for remember order. :)

Comment: Ultimately you can't depend on the actual color you get anyway. Those are just conventional defaults but the user can have customized them.

Comment: Yeah that want i trying to do. I want to have opportunity change terminal colors per host for example. And dont customise color every time inside per terminal emulator. Its work (mostly :)).

Answer (score 3):

If you convert the color numbers to binary, you will find the first bit corresponds to blue, the second bit is green and the third is red.

Example: 3<sub>10</sub>=011<sub>2</sub>=green+red=yellow

Comment: Please explain your logic for `0` and `7`. Isn't that the opposite of what you are saying. Also, do you have a reference for this?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin How are 0 and 7 the opposite of what I said? Doesn't white consist of red, green and blue?

Comment: How is mixing red, green, blue = white? I must say, the rest seem logical.

Comment: red 001 + green 010 = yellow 011, but blue 100 + magenta 101 != cyan 110. :)

Comment: Aaaaa. U right. :) That is it. Colors using binary numbers for ordering, but its standard RGB math. Hehe.

Comment: A reference for this would be amazing.

Comment: I cannot find reference yet. If anyone finds one, feel free to add another answer :)